# How to separate topics in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, rebase, mercurial-topics

I have the following structure in my mercurial branch history:

```
o topicA
|
|
o topicB
|
|
o public_branch
```

This is a linear dependency between the three, as we can see.

I need a `hg` command (or set of commands) that will result to the following structure.

```
o topicA
|
|   o topicB
| /
o public_branch
```

As you can see the two topics are now separate.

What i have tried is as simple as:

`hg rebase -s topicA_rev -d public_branch_rev`

But it replies to me `"nothing to rebase"`

Comment: I just tried this locally in a test repo and used your rebase command, it worked as expected. Using HG version 6.2.3.

Comment: I suggest posting a self-contained test script which reproduces the problem.